# How to display menu after input verification?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Main Class:

```
package BankingSystem;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank {

  public static void main (String [] args){

      //User verifies Account
        SignIn Valid = new SignIn(); 
        Valid.AccountLogin();
        Scanner choice = new Scanner (System.in);  //allow user to choose menu option 

        int option = 0; //Menu option is set to 0 


                   // Menu For User 


        do{
            System.out.println("Welcome");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1:Deposit Cash");
            System.out.println("2: Withdraw Cash");
            System.out.println("3: View Current Account Balance");
            System.out.println("4: View Saving Account Balance");


            System.out.println("5: Cancel"); //When the User Quits the system prints out GoodBye

            System.out.println("Please choose");
            option= choice.nextInt();  



  }while (option < 6);
}


  }
```

AccountLoginClass:

```
package BankingSystem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SignIn {
    public void AccountLogin (){
          List<String> AccountList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
          AccountList.add("45678690");

          Scanner AccountInput = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("What is your account number?"); 
          AccountInput.next(); 
          boolean isExist = false; 

          for  (String item : AccountList){
              if (AccountInput.equals(AccountList.get(0))){
                  System.out.println("Hi");
                  isExist = true;
                  break; 
              }

          }

          if (isExist){
              //Found In the ArrayList
          }
          }



      }
```

I am trying to create a reasonably complex Banking System. In here at the start I intend the user to input their account number which hopefully matches the Array List and when it does match the number in the ArrayList they are displayed with the menus i.e. withdraw, deposit etc.
The problem here is that I’m not sure how I can do that I created an object before the menu linking it with AccountLoginClass, but that doesn’t really work.

Comment: What do you think `AccountInput.next();` does? Which part of documentation makes you think so?

Comment: I seen it in a similar answer to what I was looking for so decided to just put it in.

Comment: But what do you think it does (I am asking since it probably doesn't do it properly)?

Comment: Another hint: `AccountInput.equals(AccountList.get(0))` doesn't do what you think (it will always return false). Try to explain what are you trying to do here and why do you think this should work.

Comment: Ok so , how I want it is that the AccountInput = 0 Index of the array which is the string "45678690" if user enters this then they are displayed with the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same mistake here as in your other questions.

```
AccountInput.equals(AccountList.get(0))
```

You are comparing instance of class java.lang.String to the instance of class java.util.Scanner. You meant:

```
(AccountInput.nextLine()).equals(AccountList.get(0))
```

This will work and you will be able to match account number to the **element of** ArrayList(not the List itself, as u wrote)

All classes in Java derived from class Object (java.lang.Object). So you may not receive an Exception sometimes, because they have different signature. Sometimes they can be equal even though they are not equal in any common sense. In good times u will receive an Exception that will crash your program.

Generally you need to make sure that you are **not** comparing **apples to oranges**.

Its very easy to check: just look at the declarations of what it is you are comparing

```
Orange or1, or2;
Apple ap1;
...
or1.equals(ap1)     // BAD
or1.equals(or2)     // Good if equals() implemented for class Orange in
                    // in the way it satisfies you.
```